# Error al crear objeto con herencias en PHP

Tags: php, poo

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con herencias de objetos. Al querer crear un nuevo objeto no lo crea. Al querer obtener el id de un objeto me devuelve:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object.

Código donde llamo a `getId()`:

```
<?php    
$controller = new TextController();
$c = $controller->getAllText();
?>
<h1> blog X</h1>
<a href="afegircontingut.html">afegir contingut</a>
<?php
  while($c){?>
<h2><?=$c->getId();?></h2>
<p><?=$c->getContingut();?></p>
```

El código que genera el objeto es este:

```
public function getAllText(){
    $this->connect();

    $s = $this->_conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM content");
    $s->execute();
    $result = $s->get_result();

     $rows =  array();
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         array_push($rows,$this->createTextFromAssoc($row));
     }
     return $rows;
}

private function createTextFromAssoc($arr){
    $text = new Text($arr['id'], $arr['titol'], $arr['data'], $arr['autor'], $arr['tipus'], $arr['contingut']);
    return $text;
}
```

#### interfaz ContentInterface.php:

```
<?php

    interface ContentInterface {
    public function getId();
    public function setId($id);

    public function getTitol();
    public function setTitol($titol);

    public function getData();
    public function setData($data);

    public function getAutor();
    public function setAutor($autor);

    public function getTipus();
    public function setTipus($tipus);

    public function getContingut();
    public function setContingut($contingut);
    }
```

#### clase abstracta ContentAbstract.php:

```
 class ContentAbstract implements ContentInterface{
 protected $id;
 protected $titol;
 protected $data;
 protected $autor;
 protected $tipus;
 protected $contingut;


    public function __construct($id = null, $titol = null, $data= null, $autor = null, $tipus = null, $contingut= null)
{
          $this->setId($id);
          $this->setTitol($titol);
          $this->setData($data);
          $this->setAutor($autor);
          $this->setTipus($tipus);
          $this->setContingut($contingut);

}

public function getId(){
    return $this->id;
}
public function setId($id){
    $this->id= $id;
}

public function getTitol(){
    return $this->titol;

}
public function setTitol($titol){
    $this->id= $id;
}

public function getData(){
    return $this->data;

}
public function setData($data){
    $this->id= $id;

}

public function getAutor(){
    return $this->autor;        
}
public function setAutor($autor){
    $this->autor= $autor;
}

public abstract function getTipus();
public abstract function setTipus($tipus);

public abstract function getContingut();
public abstract function setContingut($contingut);
}
```

#### classe Text.php:

```
class Text extends ContentAbstract{

public function  __construct(){
   parent::__construct();
 }

public function getTipus(){
    return "text";
}

public function setTipus($tipus){
    $this->tipus= $tipus;
}

public function getContingut(){
    return "contingut text";
}

public function setContingut($contingut){
    $this->contingut= $contingut;
}
}
```

Comment: En el código que has compartido no muestras dónde usas el método `getId`. El mensaje de error: ***Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object*** indica que en alguna parte estás llamando dicho método desde una instancia no válida del objeto.

Comment: @francesc, ¿Ninguna de las respuestas recibidas te ha sido de ayuda? En caso contrario, considera votar y/o marcar como acertada las respuestas que solucionaron tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

En `ContentAbstract.php` tenés varios `set` que repiten el `setId()`.

```
public function setTitol($titol){ $this->id= $id; }

public function setData($data){ $this->id= $id; }
```

Deberían asignar `$titol` y `$data`.

Answer (score 0):

El error es porque la línea `while($c){` es erronea.
La variable `$c` es un `array` de objetos `Text`.
Dado que `$c` es un `array`, esta no posee el método `getId()`.

### Solución:

Para iterar el arreglo podrías usar [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) y así acceder a los objetos `Text` dentro del mismo.

### Ejemplo:

```
<?php
foreach($c as $text){?>
<h2><?=$text->getId();?></h2>
<p><?=$text->getContingut();?></p>
```

Comment: Marcos ¿dónde estaba el método `getId()`? no lo vi al revisar la pregunta ¡y ahora aparece!.